# How to print out the input or JTextFiled

Tags: java, jtextfield, printstream

As a part of my program, I just want to print out what the user enters in the jTextField

here is what I do, but does not work at all.

```
JTextField myInput = new JTextField();
String word = myInput.getText();

myInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
System.out.print(word);
}

});
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the actionlistener you need to retrieve the value from the textfield.

```
 System.out.print(myInput.getText());
```

At the moment, you are getting a empty value because at the point where you call getText() there is nothing in the textfield because the user did not have time to type something.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but did not work: it give an error for myInput.getText(). here is the error: Cannot refer to a non-final variable myInput inside an inner class defined in a different method

Comment: So you need to declare the textfield as a instance variable. That way you will have proper access to it from within the inner class.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't updating the text (`word`) in `actionPerformed`, so it's staying the same. Try:

```
myInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
System.out.print(myInput.getText());
}
```

Therefore, you don't even need to declare `word` at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but did not work: it give an error for myInput.getText(). here is the error: Cannot refer to a non-final variable myInput inside an inner class defined in a different method

Answer (score 1):

```
final JTextField myInput = new JTextField();

myInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.print(myInput.getText());
    }
});
```

Calling `myInput.getText()` outside the `actionListener` will assign empty `string` to `word`.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  When I move the second line inside the action listener it gives the same error as system.out.print(myInput.getText); does which the error is: Cannot refer to a non-final variable myInput inside an inner class defined in a different method

Answer (score 1):

take the 2nd line inside the action performed method

Comment: I don't see why you want to set it as Final, I think it may cause trouble if u wanna change the value of it after you set it for the 1st time

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your answers.  In fact you are all right and I just need to delcare the variable as final. I still do not know why I should add that but it's working now. I hope that 'final' doesn't make make any problem later.